# How to test windows service scheduler for my ASP.Net Web Application?

Tags: asp.net, windows-services

I created a scheduler for my web app, which is setup to be fired every 3 seconds. I want to use Console.Write("bob") to see if the scheduler is working properly, but nothing happened, only the web page is created after I click the 'debug' button. Am I testing the wrong way or the scheduler is indeed not working?

Here's the code I wrote:

```
namespace Scheduler
{
    public partial class CheckExpireService : ServiceBase
    {
        private CheckExpireJob job;
        private Timer stateTimer;
        private TimerCallback timerDelegate;


        public CheckExpireService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            job = new CheckExpireJob();
            timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(job.CheckExpireApplicants);
            stateTimer = new Timer(timerDelegate, null, 1000, 3000);
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            stateTimer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}


namespace Scheduler
{
    class CheckExpireJob: ServiceBase
    {
        public void CheckExpireApplicants(object stateObject) {
        Console.Write("bob");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I was going to leave a comment, but edit and answer are the only things I seem to have available.)

First, I don't think you can run a Windows Service in Debug mode...it has to be compiled and installed as a service and started and stopped with the services manager in Windows.  If you have this code somewhere in a web application, it will not work.  It needs to be a seperate project.

Second, you can't construct and call a service like this.  If you want a service that does something on a timed interval, you need to have the timer and all of its workings within the service.

You can't schedule a web app...it runs when someone visits the page.  What is it that you REALLY need to schedule?  Regular updates of the data that the web app will pull from?

Need to know more about what you are trying to accomplish to be any help.

Comment: Hi KennyZ, I want to update my database delete the expired applicants everyday. I created the 'Scheduler' as a separate project along with my web app project. I hope these information can help you have a better understanding of what I'm trying to duo

Comment: Well, I don't know if it is considered best practice or not, but for me, I would have a completely seperate solution for the windows service.  You'll want to do a search on installing a windows service before you try to launch the thing as well.

Comment: Then, writing to the console won't work for troubleshooting the thing.  Simplest idea I can suggest is to have the test service create a file in a directory you can watch, like C:\TestFolder.  Then install and start your service, with that folder open and watch to see if the files are being created.

Comment: As you can see...this is not a trivial thing you are trying.  Much simpler would be to write a seperate windows form app and launch it with Windows Task Scheduler or something like that.

Comment: With your help, I successfully installed my scheduler(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.80).aspx). I make it as a project within my entire solution and then test it by writing a txt file. Thank you KennyZ!